# IntelliJ 2017 unexpected Python unit test behaviour

Tags: python-2.7, intellij-idea

So I recently found the awesome feature of being able to right click and run unit tests in IntelliJ premium 2017 with python plugin:

[image]

So when I run the tests from the command line they pass without issue:

[image]

[image]

Then when I try running the tests using the right click feature inside IntelliJ:

[image]

auto-generated command line options for failed test:

[image]

I tried changing the auto-generated working directory which was different to my original manual command line options run but the tests still failed the same.

The generated run configuration from the right click -> run tests IntelliJ feature(with working directory changed):

[image]

One thing I have noticed is that the file which fails to run the unit tests has many classes defined. Other test files with only 1 class defined run fine when i use the right click -> run untit test feature

UPDATE:

tried suggestions:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could it be that your unit tests are related to each other and because they are run in different order one of them is failing?

Comment: try to set path for `d:/dev/rds-sloth` and set pattern for `test_lamda_rds_rule_builder.py` instead

Comment: thanks for the replies guys. If my unit tests are running in different order and failing wouldn't that also mean they would fail from the command line? I tried changing the path and the pattern above. IntelliJ just ended up running 0 tests. I have updated the original post with this.